# How do I return the "Text" from a SelectListItem from a SelectList given a corresponding int "Value"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, selectlist

I have a `SelectList` that looks like. . .

```
new SelectList(new[]
    {
        new { Value = "1", Text = "AK" },
        new { Value = "2", Text = "AL" },
        new { Value = "3", Text = "AR" },
        new { Value = "4", Text = "AZ" },
        etc. . .
```

Given an int I need to be able to select the corresponding `Value` so I can return the associated `Text`.  So if I have the int 3, I want to ultimately return the string "AR" -- how do I do this?

I don't seem to understand how SelectLists work, I've been trying something like:

```
var stringValue = mySelectList.Where(m => m.Value == myInt).Text;
```

-- This does not work for a couple of reasons:

- .Text is not something I can put at the end of the request as it cannot be resolved
- `m.Value - myInt` tells me `I cannot convert the source type 'int' to target type 'string'`, and if I change the int to a string I get the error: `cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type 'bool'`.

I feel like I am overcomplicating something here.  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
var stringValue = mySelectList.Where(m => m.Value == myInt.ToString())
                              .First()
                              .Text;
```

- The `Where` method does not return a SelectListItem, it returns a query. You need to force the query to execute, and get the first result, by using the `First()` method.
- You're using `=` (assigning a value) instead of `==` (comparing two values).

Comment: ...or just replace Where with First.

Comment: Just be carefull with First(). It will throw an exception if no rows were found. Your should consider using FirstOrDefault() instead, and check if it's null after this LINK query. -Edit- Or simply wrap this in a try catch...

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this too

```
    var stringValue = mySelectList.Find(match => match.Value == myInt.ToString()).Text;
```

Since Find returns the first match found in the list.

Another thing your code is not working cause you typed just one "=" in your comparison and it should be like "=="
your:

```
mySelectList.Where(m => m.Value = myInt).Text
```

like it shiould be:

```
mySelectList.Where(m => m.Value == myInt).Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this;

```
 mySelectList.First(m => m.Value == myInt.ToString()).Text
```

Comment: this is still using `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = mySelectList.Where(o=> o.Value ==myInt.ToString()).Select(o=> o.Text).First();
```